# Block all RDC connection attempts except vpn

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

WinServer 08 firewall...

I'm connecting to a colocated box via hamachi's vpn - i'm hitting a specific IP on the server from a specific IP on the client and want to lock out all other RDC access.

Does this mean 2 separate rules - one to block all then one to open to the specific port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always have a "deny all" default rule in your firewall.  Thus if things aren't explicitly allowed, they will be denied.  It would be a rare thing for a firewall to not have this rule configured by default, and if you don't then you need to create it.

Assuming that is the case, you need only open the appropriate ports to the appropriate IP.  You don't have to also create deny rules for every other IP that might try to connect.

You should always test your firewall configuration with something like [Shields Up](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) (if it's on the public net) and/or [nmap](http://nmap.org/download.html) (which you run locally).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your firewall doesn't start with DENY ALL as it's default state, then yes, you'll need to do DENY ALL, and then ALLOW the particular IP address and port for the connection you want to make.